# Is trigger or alias returning data in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Postgres 9.2.2, Django 1.6.5, Python 2.7.5

```
    Column     |          Type          |         Modifiers
---------------+------------------------+------------------------------------
 id            | integer                | not null default nextval('employee_id_seq'::regclass)
 first_name    | character varying(75)  | not null
 surname       | character varying(75)  | not null
 mname         | character varying(75)  |
 date_of_birth | date                   |
 staff_id      | character varying(20)  |
 img1          | character varying(100) |
 slug          | character varying(50)  |
 created       | date                   | not null
 modified      | date                   | not null
 ppsn          | character varying(20)  |
Indexes:
    "employee_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "employee_slug_key" UNIQUE, btree (slug)
    "employee_slug_like" btree (slug varchar_pattern_ops)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "employeedynamic" CONSTRAINT "employee_id_refs_id_71e22023" FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employee(id) DEFERRABLE INITIAL
LY DEFERRED
    TABLE "drvliclicence" CONSTRAINT "employee_id_refs_id_afc65012" FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employee(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY
 DEFERRED
    TABLE "coursedetail_attendance" CONSTRAINT "employee_id_refs_id_c8466b5f" FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employee(id) DEFERRABLE
 INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

.

```
=# select a.name from employee a where a.id = 366;
(366,Tommy,Gibbons,"",1800-08-21,1002180,images/GibbonsT2010_1.
(1 row)
```

Problem: How is `a.name` returning these details?
I've tried looking up aliases and triggers but I cannot figure this.

Check trigger:

```
=# \dft
                       List of functions
 Schema | Name | Result data type | Argument data types | Type
--------+------+------------------+---------------------+------
(0 rows)
```

or

```
=# SELECT tgname FROM pg_trigger, pg_class WHERE tgrelid=pg_class.oid and relname = 'employee';
 RI_ConstraintTrigger_101722
 RI_ConstraintTrigger_101723
 RI_ConstraintTrigger_101732
 RI_ConstraintTrigger_101733
 RI_ConstraintTrigger_101737
 RI_ConstraintTrigger_101738
(6 rows)
```

Any idea how I can find what is causing `a.name` to return data?

Comment: There is no `name` field in the `employee` table you show above. Your query does not match your table definitions. What you show in the query output *looks* like a composite type, except for the lack of a closing `)`. Editing error?

Comment: @ Craig The output might need a closing ).  The query works fine even though as you rightly say `name` is not an `employee` field.  I am wondering how this is working. I cannot find an answer.  I was wondering if Django `syncdb` command somehow could create an alias or trigger in the Postgres schema.  I cannot see evidence of this in the `models.py` nor in `views.py`.  What do you mean by __composite type__ ?

Comment: Composite type is a data type created with `CREATE TYPE typename AS (...)`. Can you show the table as `CREATE TABLE` statements? You can get it from `pg_dump -t`. Also  a few lines of sample data.

Comment: CREATE TABLE employee (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(75) NOT NULL,
    surname character varying(75) NOT NULL,
    mname character varying(75),
    date_of_birth date,
    staff_id character varying(20),
    img1 character varying(100),
    slug character varying(50),
    created date NOT NULL,
    modified date NOT NULL,
    ppsn character varying(20)
);

ALTER TABLE public.employee OWNER TO postgres;

Comment: COPY employee (id, first_name, surname, mname, date_of_birth, staff_id, img1, slug, created, modified, ppsn) FROM stdin;
233 Damien Dowds \N 2068-07-31 13392 \N damiend233 2014-12-19 2014-12-19 1234567a
235 Christy Crow \N 2040-07-15 7792 \N christyc235 2014-12-19 2014-12-19 1234567a
244 John Cornally \N \N \N \N johnc244 2014-12-19 2014-12-19 \N
251 Seamus Flaherty \N \N \N \N seamusf251 2014-12-19 2014-12-19 \N

Comment: @Craig  is this what you need?  I cannot see a composite type creation in this.

Comment: Your query fails with `column a.name does not exist` when run after creating that table. There's more going on here.

Comment: @Craig. I've downloaded Postgres8.3.23-3 & 8.4.22-1, though currently using 9.2. I have also pg_dumped the db & data to an .sql file. On laptop, to test in clean environment, I installed 8.3 and psql < dump_file.sql  & sure enough _a.name_ produced an error. I then uninstalled 8.3, shutdown and then installed 8.4.  Again psql < dumpfile.  This query actually works. I ran through the install/shutdown/reinstall 8.3 first and then 8.4. Just to prove a point. 8.3 failed and 8.4 success. I am now reading through the pg_dump file (no data included). No idea what to look for though.

Comment: I have no idea what 8.3 has to do with this. Where did an old version get involved?

Comment: The query is working on my local client 9.2.2.  When my line managed installed to server 8.4.17 the query does not work.  Now I realize for some reason the query is working on 8.4.22-3.  The answer is likely to be in the dump file. There couldn't be much difference between 8.4.17 and 8.4.22 really.

Comment: That's the kind of information that should *really* be in the original question. There's no meaningful functionality difference between 8.4.17 and 8.4.22, just bug fixes.